# How to route, fetch and display data from two tables in db to a single webpage in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

im new to laravel and i am currently doing a study project in laravel 5.2. Thr project is just a simple website having 3 pages (`Home, About Us, Contact Us`) fetching each page content from database and the home page having a slideshow. For that i downloaded a free responsive html template and divided it into `header.blade.php`, `slideshow.blade.php`,`footer.blade.php` and stored it inside a folder named `includes` under `view` folder. And the main layout file `default.blade.php` is stored inside a folder named `layouts` under `view` folder. I included these `header.blade.php`, `slideshow.blade.php` and `footer.blade.php` in the main layout file `default.blade.php` to form the full web template.

My `default.blade.php` file code is as given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        @include('guest.includes.head')
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap-body">

        <header>    
            @include('guest.includes.header')
        </header>   

        @if(Request::is('/'))
            @include('guest.includes.slideshow')    
        @endif

        @yield('content')

        <footer class="zerogrid">
            @include('guest.includes.footer')
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the header.blade.php i had some information like phone num, email, website address that are fetched from database and displaying that data on all my 3 pages along with each page contents from db. For that i used `share()` function inside `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider.php` to share and display my header data on all my webpages.

and my current `slideshow.blade.php` code is like as given below:

```
<div class="zerogrid">
    <div class="callbacks_container">
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
            <li>
                <img src="assets/images/banner1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Title 1</h2></br>
                    <p>Description 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="assets/images/banner2.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Title 2</h2></br>
                    <p>Description 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see that i had hard-coded the slideshows slide item details(`slideimage, title, description`) above. Upto this part is working fine and i am getting header data from db to server via `header.blade.php` to all pages, each page contents from db via Routes/Controllers and the above said slideshow.

My `routes.php` code is as given below:

```
Route::get('/', 'GuestController@home');
Route::get('aboutus', 'GuestController@aboutus');
Route::get('contactus', 'GuestController@contactus');
```

My Controller Page(`GuestController.php`) code is as given below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
class GuestController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        $result=DB::table('contents')->where('menuname','home')->get();
        return view('guest.home')->with('data',$result);
    }   
    public function aboutus() {
        $result=DB::table('contents')->where('menuname','aboutus')->get();
        return view('guest.aboutus')->with('data',$result);
    }   
    public function contactus() {
        $result=DB::table('contents')->where('menuname','contactus')->get();
        return view('guest.contactus')->with('data',$result);
    }   
}
```

Now i want to make the slideshow also to be dynamic. I mean to fetch the slide item details (slideimage, title, description) also from db itself. For that i created a table named `slideshow` with fields `slideimage`, `title`, `description`. But i dont know how to fetch and display data from two independant tables (`slideshow` & `contents`) in db to a single web page.

(Here in my case actually in my home page it will fetch 3 sets of data from db. first set of data is header data from `headers` table that will display header data like phone, email, website etc to all my pages including homepage via `share()` function and the second set of data is the home page contents from content table via routes/controller pages. These two are already working and now iwant to fetch data for slideshow also from `slideshow` table in db which is my 3rd set of data to be display on homepage.)

Any solution for this requirement? Please Help! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

When i searched for various solutions for my requirement as asked in my above question, i found a simple method of satisfying this requirement of `fetching and displaying datas from two tables inside a single view` can be done by just modifying the `home()` method in the above given controller page code ( `GuestController.php` ) as given below:

```
public function home() {
   $homecontent=DB::table('contents')->where('menuname','home')->get();
   $slideshow=DB::table('slideshow')->get();
   return view('guest.home')->with('homecontent',$homecontent)->with('slideshow',$slideshow);
}
```

Then inside the `slideshow.blade.php` loop the result from `slideshow` variable like:

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider4">     
   @foreach($slideshow as $row)
       <li>
           <img src="assets/images/{{$row->slideimage}}" alt="">
           <div class="caption">
               <h2>{{$row->title}}</h2></br>
               <p>{{$row->description}}</p>
           </div>
       </li>          
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

and same like slideshow, loop the contents of the `homecontent` variable inside the homepage file something like:

```
@foreach($homecontent as $row)
    <article>
        <div class="art-header">
            <a href="#"><h3>{{$row->contenttitle}}</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div class="art-content">
            <img src="assets/images/{{$row->contentimage}}" />
            <p align="justify">{{$row->contentdescription}}</p>
        </div>
    </article>           
@endforeach
```

No other changes required in any other pages and it will display slideshow and homepage contents inside the homepage itself along with the shared header datas from `header` table on all pages including homepage.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I believe it should be selected as answer to the question, however please take a look at my answer too I tried to give you some ideas there. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question and you should probably select it as a answer for this thread.

(Comments are too short, that's why I am writing you an answer)

Since you said you are teaching yourself Laravel I would strongly recommend you watch [this course](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals). It is a free one and it seems to help people a lot. It certainly helped me too although I had previous experience with the framework.

Anyway you know how you write a project and then you come one year later and think "What the .. was I thinking when I wrote this?" So I believe we should name our things clearly and precisely just for the sake of saving our future selves' souls.

I hope you take this as a positive critique and not as bashing on you. With all respect to you I am just trying to convey some wisdom here...

What do I mean exactly:

1) you named your controller GuestController. But you have no `guests` table. Probably you don't have a `users` table too. So where are the guests? Your controller should be much rather named something along the lines of `HomeController` or `FrontController` or even split into may different controllers.

```
"NewsController"
```

The basic rule is "one table - one model - one controller" so first of all you should probably not keep your articles in the same table as your pages contents. What an experienced developer would do is have two separate tables for those. So probably NewsController for the news, a News model and a `news` table. Then another controller for the `pages` table, a Page model and a PagesController.

2)

```
"PagesController"
```

Here you can put your **home** and **about** pages.

so

```
class PagesController {
    public function home(){ } //will show your slideshow and news feed
    public function about() { } //will show the 'about' content from `contents`/`articles` table
}
```

then another one

```
class NewsController(){ 
    public function show($id) { } //will show a single `news` article
}
```

depending on your site architecture you can 
 - have the slides editable trough the front part of the site or have an /admin/ directory with another set of controllers where you have another **SlideController** and a **NewsController** where you can add and edit news and slides
 - or add controllers to the front part of the site to add/edit news and slides

Hope it helps along your way! 
Regards

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent)
The model is made so

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Slideshow extends Model
{
    protected $table='slideshow';
}
```

Then the controller so writing

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Slideshow;
use App\Contents;

 public function __construct(Contents $contents)
{
    $contents=$contents->get();
    view()->share('data', $contents);
}

class GuestController extends Controller
{

public function home() {
    $slideshows=Slideshow::where('menuname','home')->get();
    return view('guest.home', [ 'slideshows'=>$slideshows]);
}   
public function aboutus() {
    return view('guest.aboutus', []);
}   
public function contactus() {
    return view('guest.contactus', []);
}
```

P.S. Do not forget to register contents model

Comment: I think your method of using Eloquent model also work. But is it required for this simple requirement?? when i searched i found some other simple ways to display data from two tables in a single page and i modified my current controller ( `GuestController.php` ) page code only as per that and it works.